# Why can I not link directly to FAQ anchors?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Our [FAQ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) has some useful stuff, but it doesn't look like I can actually link people to that useful stuff. Instead I have to link them to the FAQ main page and ask them to search themselves, which is rather uncool.

For example, in the comments to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46721/compile-time-checking-for-component-based-data-driven-games) I tried to link the asker to the section of the FAQ that lists other places that are better suited to opinion-based discussion questions. The section has an anchor tag, so a link to this address

```
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#where-can-i-ask-subjective-discussion-and-other-questions-not-fit-for-this-site
```

should take you there. However, if I [create such a link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#where-can-i-ask-subjective-discussion-and-other-questions-not-fit-for-this-site), and then attempt to follow it, I'm taken the [main FAQ page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq).

I assume this is because of the fancy HTML/CSS/Javascript or whatever that's employed on the page (and as such perhaps it's a browser-specific bug -- I'm using Chrome when I see this behavior). But I feel like it's something that should work.

EDIT:
Further investigation in the chat suggests this might be because the specific section I'm trying to link to has hyphens or is otherwise long. The shorter anchors, such as [this one to information about how to ask a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), do navigate properly. So perhaps we just need to edit the FAQ and give the "where can I ask subjective stuff" section a simpler anchor.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Your answer didn't address the bug reported here.  I don't think the misbehaviour on this specific anchor tag is *actually* "by design".  Could you double-check that 'status-bydesign' is actually appropriate here?  The answer you provided two minutes after applying the tag seems to imply that you misunderstood this bug report as being confusion over the FAQ system, rather than reporting an anchor which doesn't work with the system.

Answer (score 1):

1<sup>st</sup>) There's a shortcut to the FAQ: `[faq]` and an extended one to the different topics: `[faq#TOPIC]`, where `TOPIC` is the `id/name` of the headline/anchor.

---

Example: Link to the [faq]

Example: Link to the "What kind of questions can I ask here" [faq#questions]

<sup>Note: This doesn't work in questions/answers, but in comments and in chat.</sup>

---

2<sup>nd</sup>) I also have a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3913415) that some of us over [at WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) maintain - just the text is slightly different from user to user.

Comment: [faq#where-can-i-ask-subjective-discussion-and-other-questions-not-fit-for-this-site] doesn't appear to do it, nor does [faq#3] (and in any case, do they fix the problem where the link is correct but navigating to it only takes you to the main FAQ page?

Comment: Link to the [faq] - Link to the "What kind of questions can I ask here" [faq#questions] - doesn't work in questions, but in comments and in chat.

Comment: I see. I still don't think this solves the problem though -- the /questions anchor is at the top of the page, so it's hard to tell if its navigating to the anchor. [faq#what-about-subjective-questions] doesn't navigate to the anchor ("what about subjective questions").

Answer (score 0):

Anchor links to the faq move the linked content to the top of the page (technically it's a copy, the original is still present if you scroll down).

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion for instance, leads to a page that looks like:

[image]

Comment: I noticed that, I think it's broken by anchors that have hyphens in their names, though, because that behavior isn't present for the "where-can-i-ask-subjective-discussion-and-other-questions-not-fit-for-this-site" anchor (nor the "what-about-subjective-questions" anchor).

Comment: (And if the hyphens breaking it is by design, as the tag you added to the question suggests, could you explain why?)

Comment: Those are also new(ish) sections in the FAQ so something may have been forgotten when they were added, but hopefully the design wouldn't require explicit action to make them link-able.